# Qt5.14.2 Cannot find application binary

Tags: qt, cmake, package, binary, qt-creator

When I used ***Qt5.14.2*** to open the source code of a software named ***Marble***, the compilation process went smoothly. But when ***packaging the apk***, an error message appeared as shown in the figure, indicating that ***the application binary could not be found***.

[image]

( From Qt Creator 4.11.0 (Community) )

Although I changed the Android system of various APIs, the problem has not been solved.

Souce code: https://github.com/KDE/marble/

JDK version: 8; Andriod SDK version : 25.2.5; Andriod NDK version: r20b
Andriod API : 21( Andriod 5.0.1 ), 29( Andriod10 ), 34